# Forward stdout to file in Qt Application

Tags: c++, redirect, qt4, stdout

I have a Qt application that starts several `QProcess` children and then calls `QProcess::setChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels)`. I would like to then forward stdout of this application (now containing the stdout of its children) to a log file, the location of which is determined by the application, which means I can't simply modify my logging to also write to a specified file, because that won't work for the children, and I can't run `app | tee logfile`, because I don't know where to tee it to.

I would prefer - if it exists (and I haven't been able to find it if it does) - a method to do this via Qt, but other solutions would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. As a non-Qt solution, it looks like `freopen` will do what I need it to:

```
#include <cstdio>
...
QString logFile;
...
freopen(logFile.toLocal8Bit().data(), "w", stdout);
```

Comment: i doubt this will work if multiple processes write at the same time. the c library functions dont provide any locking, and i doubt that the underlying OS API will provide such locking mechanism unless specifically asked to do so. If this solves your problem this might be the case because your logging only happens at low frequencies, so issues are highly inprobable.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it just QProcess::setStandardOutputFile() ?

Sorry never actually done this myself

Comment: Will this work for one file with multiple processes - i.e. will they all be able to write to the file and will their outputs appear sequentially?

Comment: They can probably all write to the same file but I don't know what underlying locking is used - you might get the messages from process mixed up if they run concurrently

Comment: The trouble with QProcess methods is
1) I also need the output of the original application, and I don't have access to that as a QProcess (I don't think)
2) I don't think that plays nicely with multiple processes writing to the same file.

Comment: @Matt: I dont think there is a solution for (2) which does not require to change the code of all child processes (to add inter-process synchronization).

Answer (score 1):

A *way* to do this would be to change the underlying `streambuf`, as in this fairly simple example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/

may not be the *best* way, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Looks like changing `std::cout.rdbuf()` only works for operations performed on `std::cout` - output from printf or the child processes, for example does not get forwarded.

Comment: @Matt, `printf` calls will take a different route, the above only works for cout/cerr etc. You won't get coherent output till you implement some form of IPC... (even with your `freopen` solution below) Unfortunately if you are looking to write to the same log file from multiple processes, then you need to implement some form of custom logger which works over a socket for example, and have a single process responsible for writing what is received to the file. You could also look at the boost iostreams library...